# Why do some folks use Class#method instead of Class.method in correspondence?

Tags: java

When writing about methods in Java (e.g. in forums, mailing lists, issue trackers, etc.) many people separate the method name from the class name using the '#' symbol instead of Java's native `.` operator; for example, folks refer to `Object#toString` instead of `Object.toString`. Where does this syntax come from?

Comment: Dot notation may be seen as code, where in Object.toString `Object` will be an instance or otherwise `toString` will be a static method. Dash notation is Javadoc and so is clear.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's the notation used in javadoc comments when linking to another class' method.

EDIT

To gather the additional information provided in comments:

- @Hugo notes that the `#` notation in turn comes from HTML anchors
- @maksimov points out that `Object.method` is the Java syntax to call static methods, which could be misleading

UPDATE

Java 8 brings a new syntax for method references, which now seems to become more popular - so `Object#toString` tends to now be written `Object::toString`.

Comment: This, in turn, comes from HTML Anchors, which are represented using this notation, since each method is an anchor if the HTML javadoc in generated.

Comment: all makes sense.  I may start to use it now, but I have to admit it is quite ugly and I find it harder to read.  But it does provide disambiguation in the case of static method invocations.

Comment: But what if the Object is lowercase?

Comment: Lowercase or uppercase is irrelevant. However based on javadoc, the class will be uppercase, an object instance lowercase: `Object obj`. When you want to refer to the method implementation you are supposed to use `Object#method`. Otherwise if you are talking about a specific call, then you can go with `obj.method()`.