# Create a memory leak given an interface to conform to

Tags: java

I was asked recently, the following

Given the following interface, write a class that will leak memory every time Processor#doSomething(String) is called and explain why it does so.

```
public interface Processor {
    void doSomething(String msg);
}
```

I am not sure there is memory leak in Java in the same sense as C/C++.   What is the significance of an interface here.

Also, I have never seen a # used to call a method.

Can someone explain this to me? Thanks

Comment: You should start with the link given above by @Doorknob.

Comment: `#` is just a notation. You don't see that in actual Java source code. http://stackoverflow.com/q/11247793/139010

Comment: I did see a couple references to memory leak.  I was wondering about the interface.  What is the significance of an interface?

Comment: `#` is used in javadocs, not Java source code.

Answer (score 0):

A simple implementation would have a `static` list and when `doSomething` is called, just keep adding the input `String` to the list. The reason why is because you're storing a strong reference (via the static member) to the strings so the strings cannot be garbage collected.

Comment: When you still hold a strong reference then it is not a memry leak. It is only a leak if you do nit longer have any reference but the object will still not get g/ced.

Comment: That is not the same thing as a memory leak in a C/C++ sense, where your program has no access to the memory you have leaked.  Here you do have access to the memory.

Comment: @polygnome, that's not really correct. Traditional Java usage is that an object that's referenced, but no longer needed, is a leak.

Comment: @rpat, yes, "leak" does mean something different in Java as compared to C/C++.

Comment: @Ernest Friedman-Hill: I disagree. As long as you have a strong reference, the memory is not leaked. Your object is still reachable, therefore there is no leak. There is only a leak if your object is unreachable from your code but still not g/ced. There is plenty ways of creating such a real leak even in Java, especially, but not only, when native functions are involved.

Comment: So it is not possible to have a memory leak in the C++ sense?

Comment: Still, when people say "leak" in Java, they mean simply an unintended retained reference; a common example is an event listener that is never unregistered, preventing GC for a hierarchy of components it references. You can call that whatever you like, but common usage is that it's called a leak.